# Is hiding my Java desktop app inside a VM the best way to protect my Java source code ?

Tags: java, reverse-engineering

I need to distribute a Java desktop app to the user. I am looking at different ways to protect my source code from reverse engineering.

One method is to distribute a Virtual Machine (says Linux) containing the app running inside that VM, and make the root user of that having a password of e.g. 50 characters. The drawback is that the download size of my app is too big (some Gigas). And the next question is: can an attacker read my Java code from inside a VDI disk image ?

Another method is Ahead of Time (AOT) compiling to native. ExcelsiorJet seems to be the best tool for that, however that is not free. Obfuscating the source code is NOT enough, since the ones wanting to read your source code are the ones that mainly want to care about the information flow and data structure. This [excellent article](https://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html) explains more about AOT and obfuscating. Now the question is: by using ExcelsiorJet to compile to native, is my native code relatively safe from reverse engineering ?

Still another way: to e.g. use C++ to write the most security critical code, compile it to real native, and expose my unimportant Java source. But this means I'll need to maintain both parts as well.

Comment: take a look at Minecraft, that is obfuscated, yet it's decompiled, obfuscated functions and variables are remapped and readable source code is created from it. You can't stop a good coder from figuring out your code.

Comment: Even if you wrote C++ to write your critical code, one could disassemble it.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I have rephrased my question, it focuses on VM now

Comment: @KenPo Have you considered to download the critical parts of your code at run time? Or to encrypt your code?

Comment: @LittleSanti: (1) Encryption: and how can I pass my private key to it ? (2) Downloading the critical part: would be not ultimately secure against memory dump, but is one good way to make it a bit harder for the thief, good.

Comment: @KenPo (1) You suggested yourself the root could own a robust, secret key. (2) Going further on the downloading technique, if you are willing to download code at run time, maybe you could also deploy the critical code on a remote, securized server, and let your desktop app make client calls. Then, availability and economical issues come in.